# do i have to restart the kernel everytime I run a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I am completely new in data-science and the jupyter notebook world. Is there any way to start from where I left on without restarting the whole notebook?

i.e I did some operations on a dataset and get a final_data. Whenever I want to use that final_data after shutting down and opening, I get NameError: name 'final_data' is not defined. How to solve this?

Comment: Save the data in a file. Load the data from that file. Since you are talking datascience, you could use `numpy`s  save and load operations : https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html.

Comment: This isn't a technical support forum for Jupyter.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's how the Jupyter Notebook works. You have to run all the notebook again. I go to `Cell>Run All` after opening my notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you are using Google Colab or a simple Jupyter notebook, I think you are using simple Jupyter, however, I will discuss my experience with both.

For Google Colab: Runtime is destroyed with inactivity and you have to run it again from the start.

For Jupyter Notebook: If the notebook tab is open on your browser, the results will not be cleared with time (due to inactivity) as long as you close the tab itself. If you are shutting down/restarting your pc, you will lose the progress (number of lines which were compiled and run), and there is not an easy way to save the progress.

The best way is to keep the Jupyter notebook tab open, even if you put your computer in sleep mode (by flipping the lid of your laptop), the data will be retained, until and unless you do not restart or shut down your PC.